# How to pass sslmode=require to liquibase

Tags: docker, heroku, liquibase

We run an application on Heroku and update the Database with Liquibase. Now it seems we have to pass the 'sslmode=require' URL parameter to Liquibase. The DB url itself is taken from the DATABASE_URL environment variable provided by Heroku and then the Liquibase properties are set by the entrypoint.sh script of the container that executes the migration:

echo "Use DATABASE_URL for configuration";

IFS='/'

read -ra TOKENS  <<< "$DATABASE_URL"

export LIQUIBASE_DATABASE=${TOKENS[3]}

IFS='@'

read -ra CRED_HOST_PORT <<< "${TOKENS[2]}"

IFS=':'

read -ra HOST_PORT <<< "${CRED_HOST_PORT[1]}"

export LIQUIBASE_HOST=${HOST_PORT[0]}

export LIQUIBASE_PORT=${HOST_PORT[1]}

read -ra USER_PW <<< "${CRED_HOST_PORT[0]}"

export LIQUIBASE_USERNAME=${USER_PW[0]}

export LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD=${USER_PW[1]}

So, how can we get Liquibase to connect to the Heroku Postgres DB with the sslmode=require query param?

Answer (score 0):

Had to configure env variable LIQUIBASE_URL in the entrypoint.sh file:

```
  export LIQUIBASE_URL='jdbc:postgresql://'${LIQUIBASE_HOST}':'${LIQUIBASE_PORT}'/'${LIQUIBASE_DATABASE}'?sslmode=require'
```